# What happens to the perimeter of a polygon after a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose $P$ is a polygon (in the xy plane) and it has perimeter $p$.

Then it is transformed by a 2x2 matrix $T$ which results in the new polygon $Q$ with new perimeter $q$.

What is the relationship between $p$ and $q$?  Is there some formula for $q$ in terms of $p$ and $T$?

Comment: I think if you try some experiments you will find the answer depends not just on $p$ and $T$ but on $P$ as well. Try it! Use some simple polygon, like a unit square, or a triangle.

Comment: Following Gerry's suggestion, try some simple linear maps  which scale lengths differently in the two coordinate directions.

Comment: Yes, I see.  In fact the problem is much more complex than I first thought.  I've been trying to solve it for the case where P is a regular polygon, and T is a (non-uniform) scaling - and even that relatively simple case is proving difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments already tell you, you cannot in general compute $q$ from $p$ and $T$. The reasons being that change in length of a vector unter $T$ depends on the *direction* of the vector, and $p$ doesn not include that information - it's purely a sum of lengths. Thus, to do as you ask, you need to restrict yourself to a subset of all possible $T$.

For example, if $T$ is a uniform scaling, i.e. has then form $$
  \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix}
$$
then all lenghts are simply scaled by $\lambda$ and you have $q = \lambda p$.

Similarly, if $T$ is an isometry, i.e. if it preserves lengths, you simply get $q = p$.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.  It's a good explanation of why this is not possible.